# MVC Authentication on file download

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I authenticate web users before allowing them to "src" an image or to download a file? There is also some condition that these files are publicly available.

I was thinking adding a filter in global.asax in RegisterGlobalFilters

Filter is something like..

```
public void OnFileRequest(string passToken)
{
   //validate passToken
   if (isValid(passToken))
      //allow download
   else
   {
     //authenticate using session
     if (authenticated)
        //allow download
     else
        //return exception
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly linking to actual content, store a dictionary that maps a unique identifier (GUID?) to an actual file.  Then, you can use an action result to allow the download or not.

Example:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(Guid id){
   if(SomeFunctionToDetermineIfAllowed()){
       return new FileResult(...);
   }else{
       return RedirectToAction("NotFound");
   }
}
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing right now and it is taking time to stream files as a result.

Comment: What does that mean, takes time to stream files?  The check for authorization should literally be in milliseconds unless you have a very strange / non-optimized authorization in place.  Now, if the file is of some non-negligible size, then yes, downloading the file will take some amount of time.

Comment: Yes this is not a problem if there's only a minimal user access. I am working on a multi-company site and there will be a lot of user requests to access or to source files. Streaming files will consume memory resources and it might be a problem in the future.

Comment: @evilom - though I have not seen any evidence that will support what you just mentioned (besides maybe the overhead of having to go through the .NET pipeline vs. static file download), I can say that on sites with plenty of users, we have successfully implemented such a plan.  Have you measured the speed differences between static file request vs the way you are doing it?  I only ask because you are going to need something between a file and a user which will require additional overhead.

Comment: You might also need to add OutputCacheAttribute to your Action method to ensure caching is configured similarly to static files.  Difference in caching configuration might account for the perceived performance difference.

Comment: files are very dynamic so I need to break the cache on each request..and it is actually a gallery so each user might request a hundred times at once..plus the api that also does the same for the devices. And as I have mentioned before this is a multi-tenant system in which users with a bunch of request like this will swarm the system.

Answer (score 0):

Use forms authentication and check for cookies.

Comment: there's a certain condition where those files are available in public. I have updated my question.

Comment: This answer does not address how the OP might do this for binary files as opposed to pages or MVC views managed by the ASP.NET runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The Files that are stored in some Folder, which can be downloaded on request(with authenticated user)

To Achieve this please follow the steps.

- The Folder ( where files stored ) must have an web.config file or the normal web.config file must have definition to **restrict the user authentication to Authenticated user only**.
  using following xml Tags.

  ```
  <location path="~/Download_url_page(Folder,File url).aspx">

      <system.web>

          <authorization>

          <allow users="John"/> // allow John to Download file.
          <deny users="*"/>  // deny others

          </authorization>

      </system.web>

  </location>
  ```

Same way the logged in user(specific)  / logged in users (not specific but authenticated users) . the download can be restricted.

`<authorization>`

`<deny users="?"/>  //this will restrict anonymous user access`

`</authorization>`

I hope this solves your Problem.

Comment: there's a certain condition where those files are available in public. I have updated my question.

Comment: This only works for file typess registered to be handled by aspnet